# How to change the size of Checkbox within the Virtual Table column in eclipse SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

In my application I have used Virtual Table, in that first column contains checkbox, I have implemented Select all checkbox in Column header, by using two image of Checkbox State selected and unselected view with size of 16x16px. Now when we look at the UI, both Select all and item checkbox looks different.

I have tried Select all check box to match item checkbox by increasing image size, but no effect on increasing the size, so I decided to change the size of item checkbox but I don't know how to do either.

I want to have both checkbox in same size, no problem whether to increase the size of select all or decrease the size of item checkbox.

Thanks in Advance!

This is how it currently looks like:

[image: Both are in different size]

This is my code for adding items to column and handling select all check box:

```
    public final void addColumn(@NotNull final Column<E> column, boolean isSelectColumn) {
        Util.checkNotNull(column);
        columns.add(column);

        final TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(table, column.orientation);
        tableColumn.setText(column.label);
        tableColumn.setToolTipText(column.getToolTipText());

        column.evtLabelChanged.add(new Event.Listener<String>() {
            public void update(String eventData) {
                tableColumn.setText(eventData);
            }
        });
        if (isSelectColumn) {
            tableColumn.setImage(Img.CHECKBOX_UNCHECKED.get());

            tableColumn.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> {
                if (tableColumn.getImage() == Img.CHECKBOX_UNCHECKED.get()) {
                    tableColumn.setImage(Img.CHECKBOX_CHECKED.get());
                    isAllSelected = true;
                } else {
                    tableColumn.setImage(Img.CHECKBOX_UNCHECKED.get());
                    isAllSelected = false;
                }
                for (TableItem item : table.getItems()) {
                    item.setChecked(isAllSelected);
                }
                table.redraw();
                Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> {
                    List<ResultDocument> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (TableItem item : table.getItems()) {
                        if (item.getChecked()) {
                            selectedItems.add((ResultDocument) item.getData());
                        }
                    }
                    ResultPanel.selDocument.addAll(selectedItems);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the code for Adding columns to the table:

```
public final class ResultPanel {

    // TODO post-release-1.1: show an additional icon if an email has attachments
    // TODO post-release-1.1: show some helpful overlay message if a search yielded no results
    // TODO post-release-1.1: implement context menu: copy paths to clipboard, including Mod1+C shortcut (also: Mod1+A for selecting all items)

    public enum HeaderMode {
        FILES { protected void setLabel(VariableHeaderColumn<?> column) {
            column.setLabel(column.fileHeader);
        } },
        EMAILS { protected void setLabel(VariableHeaderColumn<?> column) {
            column.setLabel(column.emailHeader);
        } },
        FILES_AND_EMAILS { protected void setLabel(VariableHeaderColumn<?> column) {
            column.setLabel(column.combinedHeader);
        } };

        protected abstract void setLabel(@NotNull VariableHeaderColumn<?> column);

        @NotNull
        public static HeaderMode getInstance(boolean filesFound, boolean emailsFound) {
            final HeaderMode mode;
            if (filesFound)
                mode = emailsFound ? HeaderMode.FILES_AND_EMAILS : HeaderMode.FILES;
            else
                mode = HeaderMode.EMAILS;
            return mode;
        }
    }

    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

    public final Event<List<ResultDocument>> evtSelection = new Event<List<ResultDocument>> ();
    public final Event<Void> evtHideInSystemTray = new Event<Void>();

    private final VirtualTableViewer<ResultDocument> viewer;
    private final FileIconCache iconCache;
    public static ArrayList<ResultDocument> selDocument = new ArrayList<>();

    private HeaderMode presetHeaderMode = HeaderMode.FILES; // externally suggested header mode
    private HeaderMode actualHeaderMode = HeaderMode.FILES; // header mode after examining each visible element

    public ResultPanel(@NotNull Composite parent) {
        iconCache = new FileIconCache(parent);
        
        int treeStyle = SWT.CHECK | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER;
        viewer = new VirtualTableViewer<ResultDocument> (parent, treeStyle) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            protected List<ResultDocument> getElements(Object rootElement) {
                return (List<ResultDocument>) rootElement;
            }
        };

        // Open result document on double-click
        final Table table = viewer.getControl();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
                launchSelection();
            }
        });

        table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (UtilGui.isEnterKey(e.keyCode))
                    launchSelection();
                else if (e.stateMask == SWT.MOD1 && e.keyCode == 'c')
                    copyToClipboard();
                else if (e.stateMask == SWT.MOD1 && e.keyCode == 'a')
                    table.selectAll();
            }
        });

        viewer.setSortingEnabled(true);
        initContextMenu();

        table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                evtSelection.fire(viewer.getSelection());
            }
        });


        table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event e) {
                if(e.detail == SWT.CHECK)
                {
                    viewer.getSelection();
                    handleTableSelection(e);
                }
            }
        });



        viewer.addColumn(new Column<ResultDocument>(Msg.select.get(), SWT.CENTER) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return "";
            }

            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                // This column doesn't participate in sorting
                return 0;
            }

        }, true);


        viewer.addColumn(new VariableHeaderColumn<ResultDocument>(Msg.title.get(), Msg.subject.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return element.getTitle();
            }
            protected Image getImage(ResultDocument element) {
                if (element.isEmail())
                    return Img.EMAIL.get();
                return iconCache.getIcon(element.getFilename(), Img.FILE.get());
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return compareAlphanum(e1.getTitle(), e2.getTitle());
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new Column<ResultDocument>(Msg.score.get(), SWT.RIGHT) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return String.valueOf(element.getScore());
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return -1 * Float.compare(e1.getScore(), e2.getScore());
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new Column<ResultDocument>(Msg.size.get(), SWT.RIGHT) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return String.format("%,d KB", element.getSizeInKB());
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return -1 * Longs.compare(e1.getSizeInKB(), e2.getSizeInKB());
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new VariableHeaderColumn<ResultDocument>(Msg.filename.get(), Msg.sender.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                if (element.isEmail())
                    return element.getSender();
                return element.getFilename();
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return compareAlphanum(getLabel(e1), getLabel(e2));
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new Column<ResultDocument>(Msg.type.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return element.getType();
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return compareAlphanum(e1.getType(), e2.getType());
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new Column<ResultDocument>(Msg.path.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return element.getPath().getPath();
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return compareAlphanum(getLabel(e1), getLabel(e2));
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new VariableHeaderColumn<ResultDocument>(Msg.authors.get(), Msg.sender.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                return element.getAuthors();
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                return compareAlphanum(e1.getAuthors(), e2.getAuthors());
            }
        }, false);

        viewer.addColumn(new VariableHeaderColumn<ResultDocument>(Msg.last_modified.get(), Msg.send_date.get()) {
            protected String getLabel(ResultDocument element) {
                Date date = getDate(element);
                return date == null ? "" : dateFormat.format(date);
            }
            protected int compare(ResultDocument e1, ResultDocument e2) {
                Date date1 = getDate(e1);
                Date date2 = getDate(e2);
                if (date1 == null) // Place null dates before non-null dates
                    return date2 == null ? 0 : -1;
                else if (date2 == null)
                    return 1;
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            }
            @Nullable
            private Date getDate(ResultDocument element) {
                if (element.isEmail())
                    return element.getDate();
                return element.getLastModified();
            }
        }, false);

        SettingsConf.ColumnWidths.ResultPanel.bind(table);
        SettingsConf.ColumnOrder.ResultPanelColumnOrder.bind(table);
    }

    private void launchSelection() {
        List<ResultDocument> selection = viewer.getSelection();
        if (selection.isEmpty())
            return;
        ResultDocument doc = selection.get(0);
        if (!doc.isEmail())
            launchFiles(Collections.singletonList(doc));
    }

    private static int compareAlphanum(@NotNull String s1, @NotNull String s2) {
        return AlphanumComparator.ignoreCaseInstance.compare(s1, s2);
    }

    private void initContextMenu() {
        ContextMenuManager menuManager = new ContextMenuManager(viewer.getControl());

        menuManager.add(new MenuAction(Msg.open.get()) {
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                List<ResultDocument> sel = viewer.getSelection();
                if (sel.isEmpty())
                    return false;
                for (ResultDocument doc : sel)
                    if (doc.isEmail())
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
            public void run() {
                launchFiles(viewer.getSelection());
            }
            public boolean isDefaultItem() {
                return true;
            }
        });

        menuManager.add(new MenuAction(Msg.open_parent.get()) {
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                return !viewer.getSelection().isEmpty();
            }
            public void run() {
                MultiFileLauncher launcher = new MultiFileLauncher();
                for (ResultDocument doc : viewer.getSelection()) {
                    Path path = doc.getPath();
                    try {
                        launcher.addFile(getParent(path));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        launcher.addMissing(path.getCanonicalPath());
                    }
                }
                if (launcher.launch() && SettingsConf.Bool.HideOnOpen.get())
                    evtHideInSystemTray.fire(null);
            }
            @NotNull
            private File getParent(@NotNull Path path)
                    throws FileNotFoundException {
                /*
                 * The possible cases:
                 * - Path points to an ordinary file
                 * - Path points to an archive entry
                 * - Path points to an item in a PST file
                 *
                 * In each case, the target may or may not exist.
                 */
                PathParts pathParts = path.splitAtExistingFile();

                if (pathParts.getRight().isEmpty()) // Existing ordinary file
                    return Util.getParentFile(path.getCanonicalFile());

                File leftFile = pathParts.getLeft().getCanonicalFile();
                if (leftFile.isDirectory())
                    // File, archive entry or PST item does not exist
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();

                // Existing PST item
                if (Util.hasExtension(pathParts.getLeft().getName(), "pst"))
                    return Util.getParentFile(leftFile);

                // Existing archive entry -> return the archive
                return leftFile;
            }
        });

        menuManager.addSeparator();

        String label = Util.IS_MAC_OS_X ? Msg.copy_macosx.get() : Msg.copy.get();
        menuManager.add(new MenuAction(label) {
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                return !viewer.getSelection().isEmpty();
            }
            public void run() {
                copyToClipboard();
            }
        });
    }

    private void copyToClipboard() {
        List<ResultDocument> docs = getSelection();
        if (docs.isEmpty())
            return;
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(docs.size());
        for (ResultDocument doc : docs)
            files.add(doc.getPath().getCanonicalFile());
        UtilGui.setClipboard(files);
    }

    @NotNull
    public Table getControl() {
        return viewer.getControl();
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return viewer.getControl().getItemCount();
    }

    @MutableCopy
    @NotNull
    public List<ResultDocument> getSelection() {
        return viewer.getSelection();
    }

    // header mode: auto-detect for "files + emails", no auto-detect for files and emails mode
    public void setResults( @NotNull List<ResultDocument> results,
                               @NotNull HeaderMode headerMode) {
        Util.checkNotNull(results, headerMode);

        if (this.presetHeaderMode != headerMode) {
            if (headerMode != HeaderMode.FILES_AND_EMAILS)
                updateColumnHeaders(headerMode);
            this.presetHeaderMode = headerMode;
        }
        setActualHeaderMode(results); // TODO post-release-1.1: needs some refactoring

        viewer.setRoot(results);
        viewer.scrollToTop();
    }

    private void setActualHeaderMode(List<ResultDocument> elements) {
        if (presetHeaderMode != HeaderMode.FILES_AND_EMAILS) {
            actualHeaderMode = presetHeaderMode;
            return;
        }
        boolean filesFound = false;
        boolean emailsFound = false;
        for (ResultDocument element : elements) {
            if (element.isEmail())
                emailsFound = true;
            else
                filesFound = true;
        }
        actualHeaderMode = HeaderMode.getInstance(filesFound, emailsFound);
        updateColumnHeaders(actualHeaderMode);
    }

    private void updateColumnHeaders(HeaderMode headerMode) {
        for (Column<ResultDocument> column : viewer.getColumns()) {
            if (! (column instanceof VariableHeaderColumn)) continue;
            headerMode.setLabel((VariableHeaderColumn<?>) column);
        }
    }

    // sign of given index specifies direction of sorting
    // zero and out-of-range values will be ignored
    // column numbering starts at 1
    // the index points at the column in visual order, not in creation order
    public void sortByColumn(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0)
            return;
        /*
         * Note: The column to sort by must be specified as an index, since the
         * column names may change.
         */
        try {
            int index = Math.abs(columnIndex) - 1;
            List<Column<ResultDocument>> columns = viewer.getColumnsVisualOrder();
            if (index >= columns.size())
                return;
            boolean up = Math.signum(columnIndex) > 0;
            viewer.sortByColumn(columns.get(index), up);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // Should not be called with email
    private void launchFiles(@NotNull List<ResultDocument> docs) {
        assert !docs.isEmpty();
        MultiFileLauncher launcher = new MultiFileLauncher();
        Set<FileResource> resources = new HashSet<FileResource>();
        try {
            for (ResultDocument doc : docs) {
                try {
                    FileResource fileResource = doc.getFileResource();
                    resources.add(fileResource);
                    launcher.addFile(fileResource.getFile());
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    launcher.addMissing(doc.getPath().getCanonicalPath());
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    AppUtil.showError(e.getMessage(), true, false);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (launcher.launch() && SettingsConf.Bool.HideOnOpen.get())
                evtHideInSystemTray.fire(null);
        }
        finally {
            for (FileResource fileResource : resources)
                fileResource.dispose();
        }
    }

    private static abstract class VariableHeaderColumn<T> extends Column<T> {
        private final String fileHeader;
        private final String emailHeader;
        private final String combinedHeader;

        public VariableHeaderColumn(@NotNull String fileHeader,
                                    @NotNull String emailHeader) {
            super(fileHeader);
            Util.checkNotNull(fileHeader, emailHeader);
            this.fileHeader = fileHeader;
            this.emailHeader = emailHeader;
            combinedHeader = fileHeader + " / " + emailHeader;
        }
    }



    private void handleTableSelection(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event event) {
        TableItem tableItem = (TableItem) event.item;
        if (tableItem != null) {
            ResultDocument selectedDocument = (ResultDocument) tableItem.getData();
            if (selectedDocument != null) {
                if (tableItem.getChecked()) {
                    selDocument.add(selectedDocument);
                } else {
                    selDocument.remove(selectedDocument);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't really have any control over how the TableColumn draws the image. On a quick test here a 16x16 image is not resized on macOS so it is probably also dependent on the OS.

Comment: Is it possible to resize the checkbox items inside the column? Not the header one! @greg-449

Comment: Only by using a different sized image or a "owner draw" table where you draw the rows yourself - using EraseItem, MeasureItem, PaintItem events. But you can't really find out what size the column header is using so working out the correct size would be a problem.